# JSON Undefined Error in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have this JS function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ShowBMI() {
        $.getJSON('/BMICalculations/ShowBMI', function (data) {
            alert(data.CalculatedBMIResult);
        });
    });
```

And in my BMICalculations controller I have this method:

```
 public JsonResult ShowBMI(){
        BMICalculation BMI = new BMICalculation();
        var data = Json(new
        {
            CalculatedBMIResult = 6
        });
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I call the JS function using the Onclick event of my submit button. The JS alert says 'undefined'. My Chrome console says that ShowBMI() is undefined but how could this be? Since its defined properly in my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Json` method returns a `JsonResult` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504936%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and not the converted JSON.

So you will end up wrapping your data to a `JsonResult` and sending the wrapper object to your client instead of your original data.

To fix this you just need to remove your first `Json` call when creating the `data`:

```
public JsonResult ShowBMI()
{
    BMICalculation BMI = new BMICalculation();
    var data = new
    {
        CalculatedBMIResult = 6
    };
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```